# Alert срабатывает несколько раз при посылке запроса

Tags: javascript, java

имеется страница :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>L2.1</title>
    <script>

        function signUpAction(){
            console.log("Sign Up");

            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            var log = document.getElementById('login').value;
            var pas = document.getElementById('password').value;

            xhr.open('POST', '/reg', true);   

            var body = 'login=' + encodeURIComponent(log) +
                       '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pas);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
            } else {
                alert( xhr.responseText ); 
            }
            };

            xhr.send(body);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome</p>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Login: <input id="login" type="text" name="login"/>
    Password: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"/>

</form>
<button name="SignUp" onclick="signUpAction()">Sign Up </button>
</body>
</html>
```

И написан сервлет для принятия запросов по `URI  /reg` :

```
public class SingUpServlet extends HttpServlet {

    AccountService accountService;

    public SingUpServlet(AccountService accountService){
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Map<String, Object> requestParams = getRequestParameters(req);

        resp.getWriter().print("SIGNING UP doGET");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Map<String, Object> requestParams = getRequestParameters(req);

        resp.getWriter().print("SIGNING UP");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getRequestParameters(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("pathInfo", req.getPathInfo());
        map.put("context", req.getContextPath());
        map.put("method", req.getMethod());
        map.put("session", req.getSession().getId());
        map.put("URL", req.getRequestURI().toString());    
        map.put("body", req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));    
        System.out.println("dobody: " + map.get("body"));    
        return map;
    }
}
```

После нажатия на кнопку запрос летит на сервер и возвращает обратно ответ.
По идее алерт должен сработать один раз и вывести ссобщение с сервера, однако он срабатывает 3 раза:

сначало алерт с пустым сообщением
потом 2 алерта с текстом из ответа.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем случае нужно проверить xhr.readyState, т.к. функция onreadystatechange ждет, пока совершится запрос (У вас xhr.readyState сначала равна 2, а потом 4, поэтому и два alert). Цифра 4 -- обозначает запрос, который финишировал;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>L2.1</title>
    <script>

        function signUpAction(){
            console.log("Sign Up");

            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            var log = document.getElementById('login').value;
            var pas = document.getElementById('password').value;

            xhr.open('POST', '/reg', true);   

            var body = 'login=' + encodeURIComponent(log) +
                       '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pas);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
                  if (xhr.status != 200) {
                  alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
                } else {
                   alert( xhr.responseText ); 
                 }
               }
            };

            xhr.send(body);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome</p>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Login: <input id="login" type="text" name="login"/>
    Password: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"/>

</form>
<button name="SignUp" onclick="signUpAction()">Sign Up </button>
</body>
</html>
```